# How to call a base-class operator?

Tags: c#

So, I want to do something like:

```
 Class A
{
    public static A operator + (A left, A right)
    {
        //Calculations
        return new A();
    }
}

Class B : A
{
    public static B operator + (B left, B right)
    {
        //Calculations
        base.+(left,right);
        return new A();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Edit:

Would be nice to achieve this without type-cast to base class, because it gets ugly:

```
public static Sums operator -(Sums operand1, Sums operand2)
{
   Sums res = new Sums(operand1._parent);
   res = (Sums) (operand1 - (srp_AccountPension.PensionSums)operand2);
   return res;

 }
```

I don't like the back-and-forward casting to base class and again to derived class...

Comment: `A` doesn't have `-` operator. Did you meant `+`?

Comment: Yep, it's just an small example

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The question is "How to call a base-class operator"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefining a static method like that is not something looking good. My suggestion is to use Template Method design pattern, and that makes the + operator a template method,

```
class A
{
    public virtual A Plus(A right)
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public static A operator + (A left, A right)
    {
        //Calculations and handle left == null case.
        return left.Plus(right);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override B Plus(B right)
    {
        //Calculations
        base.Plus(right);
        return new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, really nice answer, short question: is this really a template method pattern? From GoF template method contains some steps, which can be overriden in derived classes. In this scenario it's seems like a very-very degenerate case of template method with one step

Comment: Well, "some steps" can also accept "one step". If we follow the Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern, then "one or more algorithm steps can be overridden by subclasses" is clear enough to accept "one step" case.

Comment: yes, one or more steps can be overridden. But the template method itself should contain more than one steps. Otherwise, it's just a delegation. I haven't saw some examples of template methods, where the body of template method contained simply one method call. Don't get me wrong, I've just meet this situations at work, where presumably lots of template methods where implemented, where in fact it was just a method delegation.

Answer (score 4):

Just simply call `+` operator for two arguments. One of the has type `A` (the left one should always the of type, that is the container of the overloaded operator)

```
public class A
{
    public static A operator + (A left, A right)
    {
        //Calculations
        Console.WriteLine ("base A was called");
        return new A();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static B operator + (B left, B right)
    {
        //Calculations
        A res = right + (A)left;
        return new B();
    }
}
```

now calling

```
var B = new B() + new B();
```

will print:

```
base A was called
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without type-cast? because it hets ugly 

`public static Sums operator -(Sums operand1, Sums operand2)
      {
         Sums res = new Sums(operand1._parent);
         res = (Sums) (operand1 - (srp_AccountPension.PensionSums)operand2);
         return res;

      }`

Comment: @Anarion could you please give the full example in the question and highlight your concert?